# Image r1 moves when resized

Tags: css

I need to do a position: absolute on my r1 class rose.The problem is it
            moves position when I resize the browser.No other element including images do this until I attempt to use the position: absolute element.I know there are other ways to maybe accomplish this but I really need to learn how to use this in a responsive design.My website is www.michaelmorris.website.The way that I want to style this is vertical links on the left with two roses stacked vertically
            to the right of the links.One large save the date image centered in the middle and two vertically stacked rose images on the right.I do have a screenshot from a previous attempt to use position: absolute were I was able to achieve this design but the problem was that it wasn 't responsive. Would of posted code but i highlight everything an use the control K and it still will not allow me to post. I also used Chrome'
            beautify and it still will not allow me to post.

```
<div id="MasterContainer">
        <section>
         <ul id="tes">
        <li class="l"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="l"><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
    <li class"l"><a href="MessageBoard.php">Messages</a></li>
    <li class"l"><a href="About.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="r1"><img src="http://michaelmorris.website/Images/Roses.jpg"> `enter code here`</li>  
<section>


img{
    max-width: 100%;
    }
    #tes{
    margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;hnnbvcxzbc
    border: 5px solid #eee8aa; 
    }
    li a{
    color: #FFFFFF;
     font-size:1.82em;
        font-style:italic;
        list-style: none;
    }
    #MasterContainer{
        width: 100%;
      margin: 0%;
      padding: 0 5%;
        }
    .r1{    
          width: 10%;
       position: absolute;
       top: 10%;
       left: 10%;
      float: left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well offhand your r1 class sets its width, top and left to be 10% of its parent container... so when you resize the browser the 10% is of course going to change... you should be using pixels instead of percentages. See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: It still moves even when using px as the value. Thanks anyway

Comment: Yeah, you're using 5% padding on the parent container too. Anything percentage based is going to change according to the size of the browser. Use pixels instead.

Comment: #MasterContainer{
  width: 960px;
   margin: 0px;
 
  }
 .r1{   
    width: 100px;;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 60px;
  
 }

Comment: Made these changes here and also used percentage for the width in the parent container and still the same thing. The image moves about 10-20 pixels when resized Not sure what other combination I could do.

Comment: I've positioned absolute all of my images to give you an idea what I would like to do. I can post the full code if need be.